# If I'm logged in as root, how do I restart mysql or apache with options?

Tags: command-line, mysql, apache-httpd, options

I know the commands to restart/stop/start, but when I try to pass options it doesn't seem to work!

CENTOS 6, MySQL 5.14

```
service mysql restart
service httpd restart
```

Then I tried this:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql --general_log /my/log/path.log
```

That doesn't work either (the error message says it doesn't have access) =/

**Update: Apparently I can't run `mysqld` as root because of security issues**

Comment: Doesn't work meaning what? Do you get errors? If not, how do you know it doesn't work? Does anything appear in the logs (files under `/var/log`)? What user are you running these commands as? What OS are you running?

Comment: running as root on CentOS 6 / Yum RPM mysql.1.42-community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change options permanently and in the sanctioned manner, edit the files in `/etc/sysconfig` that have the same name as the service.

For example, consider `httpd`. On one system I have, there are several things you can set:

```
# Processing model
HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker

# Additional options
OPTIONS=

# Set locale
HTTPD_LANG=C
```

(The actual file is much more verbose and explanatory than this.)

There should be files in `/etc/sysconfig` for virtually every service.